# jQuery UI Drag and Drop—Draggable elements won't move horizontally?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable

I'm learning jQuery UI Drag and Drop. I've got vanilla code. I'd like the draggables to be able to drag horizontally and vertically. For some reason the draggables won't move horizontally yet.

**JS:**

```
$('.draggable').draggable({
    containment: '#containerForDraggables',
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="containerForDraggables">
    <p class="draggable">Draggable #1</p>
    <p class="draggable">Draggable #2</p>
    <p class="draggable">Draggable #3</p>
</div>
```

Here's a jsfiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/VikR0001/dv48y1rb/15/

What am I missing?

Thanks very much in advance to all for any info.

Comment: Your `.draggable` elements are full width. Therefore, they can't move side to side and still stay within the container. Try either adding a static width or setting them to inline elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't drag the `p` elements horizontally because you have `containment` set to their parent element and they have a width of `100%` by default (since they are block-level elements).

You could either set a width on the elements that is less than `100%` of its parent element. Alternatively, the better option would be to float the elements so that they have a ["shink-to-fit" width](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#shrink-to-fit-float) based on their contents:

[**Updated Example**](https://jsfiddle.net/74p8h5ty/)

```
#containerForDraggables .draggable {
  cursor: pointer;
  float: left;
  clear: both;
}
```

Setting the `display` to `inline-block` would work as well, but then you wouldn't be able to use `clear: both` to break the elements to new lines.