# jQuery draggable and resizable combo is sticking the element to the side of the container in Safari

Tags: jquery

I am using Resizable and Draggable on a table element that I need to be able to move around, but also need it to be constrained to another table element.

This works fine in Chrome, but I am finding that in Safari, when I resize the element and then drag it, it locks itself to the left side of the container and I can't pry it loose.  Is there a setting I can use to resolve this?  See example in Safari with this JSFiddle.

```
$('#floater').resizable({
    handles: "n, e, s, w, ne, se, sw, nw",
    containment: "parent"


  });


 $('#floater').draggable({
    axis: "y,x",
    containment: "#video-area"

});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xstatic/scna5r3v/52/

Comment: This could be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34754168/jquery-ui-drag-and-drop-draggable-elements-wont-move-horizontally   Try setting ".inner-box", '#video-area' and #floater's display property to "inline-block"   https://jsfiddle.net/a1utnv6h/

Comment: That was helpful!  If you want to make that an answer Ill vote it, or I can delete this if it appears to be a duplicate.  Thanks!

Comment: Glad that it helped. I made my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set ".inner-box", ".video-area" and "#floater" display property to "inline-block". 
 https://jsfiddle.net/a1utnv6h/.

```
.inner-box {
  position: absolute;
  display:inline-block;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  background: white;
}

#video-area {
  height:100%;
  width:100%;
  background:red;
  table-layout: fixed !important;
  display:inline-block;
}

#floater {
  position:absolute;
  display:inline-block;
  width:98%;
  background:white;
  color:black;
  margin-left: auto !important;
  margin-right: auto !important;
  cursor: move;
  padding:10px;
  top:20px;
}
```